# Gulp tasks do not exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, nodes

I have a `gulpfile.js` which has a bunch of tasks.

I noticed that my gulp tasks run, but after finishing they don't exit/terminate. I have to use `control + c` to exit. 
I went through a thread that talked about a similar problem, but it was using gulp-mocha and there was an issue in the plug in.

In my case, I also know what is causing this issue. I have required a js(`edgecaset.js`) file that I've written, into my gulp file (one of the tasks uses a function in that file). It is a simple file with one function that interacts with a rest api. If I don't require that file, everything works great.

I'm exporting just one function from the `edgecast.js` file to be used in the gulp file. It has a call to the `setTimeOut` function (could that be the problem?)

Can anyone help me find out the problem?

```
var main = function () {
    console.log(config.edgecast.username);
    ftp.put(config.ftp.local_path, config.ftp.remote_path, function(hadError) {
        if (!hadError) {
            console.log('File transferred successfully');
            rest.put(config.edgecast.purge_url, purgeOptions).on('complete', function(data, response) {
                if (response.statusCode != 200)
                    console.log('Purge failed');
                else {
                    console.log('Purge request Issued');
                    purgeID = data.Id;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        rest.get(config.edgecast.get_purge_url + purgeID, purgeOptions).on('complete', function(data) {
                            if (data.CompleteDate) {
                                console.log('Purge completed on ' + data.CompleteDate);
                                rest.put(config.edgecast.load_url, loadOptions).on('complete', function(data, response) {
                                    if (response.statusCode == 200)
                                        console.log('Asset Loaded');
                                    else {
                                        console.log('Load Failed');
                                        console.log(response.statusCode);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }, 180000);
                }
            });
        } else console.log('File Transfer Failed. ' + hadError);
        ftp.raw.quit(function(err) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
        });
    });
};
```

Above is the function I'm exporting from the edgecast.js file. This is the only function in the file. The rest is only variables. And then in the gulpfile.js there is

var edgecast = require('./edgecast.js');

And this require statement causes all the problems.

The edgecast.js file has the following libraries imported.

```
var rest = require('restler'),
    config = require('./config'),
    JSFtp = require('jsftp');
```

Comment: Add some code, please.

Comment: Added. I should have probably done that before.

Comment: Found the problem. Turns out gulp tasks don't exit because the FTP connection was left open and they wait until it is closed.

Comment: @OmkarSambhus I had a similar issue with a plugin I was working on where it had  a connection open to a database left open, and that caused the task to hang. This is the only place I could get a hint on how to solve it. Please add your comment as an answer, and mark it so it could help others.

Comment: @BuddhiP Added my comment as answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Turns out gulp tasks don't exit because the FTP connection was left open and they wait until it is closed